# Text positiong in cell (tabular)

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment

I'm using the `beamer` class and this code:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|}\hline
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{2_1} &  hey ho \\ \hline 
s & ho  hey \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

and I get this output:

[image: tabular_image]

How can I make the "hey ho" text stay on top of it's cell? I'd like for it to stay attached to the top horizontal line, not the bottom one.

I tried substituting it with `\vtop{\hbox{hey ho}}` (only hint I could google up) but the result is the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While `\vtop` goes into the right direction applying it to "hey ho" doesn't help because the image causes the cell to be very high while the *baseline* (the logical line where the text sits on) is at the bottom of the image. This places the text in the other cell of the same row at the bottom. A way to fix this is to lower the image below the baseline, which will effectively raise the baseline and so the text sitting on it.

You can use the `\raisebox{<length>}{<content>}` macro to raise or lower the image. I would say lower it to the `\height` of the image minus the height of the text (given by `\ht\strutbox`):

(The `demo` mode is used here so the image is not required to compile the file. A black box is shown instead. Just remove the stuff for your file.)

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|}\hline
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\height\relax}{\includegraphics[draft,height=2cm,width=5cm,scale=0.4]{2_1}} & hey ho \\ \hline 
s & ho  hey \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: good explanation and example code! I'll remove my similar `\raisebox` answer since I prefer yours.